# Python - When to use file vs open

Tags: python, file

What's the difference between `file` and `open` in Python?  When should I use which one?  (Say I'm in 2.5)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You should always use `open()`.

As the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) states:

> When opening a file, it's preferable
>   to use open() instead of invoking this
>   constructor directly. file is more
>   suited to type testing (for example,
>   writing "isinstance(f, file)").

Also, `file()` [has been removed](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins) since Python 3.0.

Comment: This is distressing, since the documentation used to state "The file() constructor is new in Python 2.2. The previous spelling, open(), is retained for compatibility, and is an alias for file()." Since I decided to RTFM ten years ago, and became very fond the the unification of types and classes, I never used open() again.  Moreover, I still feel that the type constructor is the more obvious way to return a file like object, located by the path arg, and behaving as requested in the mode arg.  I especially feel this way when the obvious intent of the devs back then was 2 retain open4compat.

Answer (score 33):

Two reasons: The python philosophy of "There ought to be one way to do it" and `file` is going away.

`file` is the actual type (using e.g. `file('myfile.txt')` is calling its constructor). `open` is a factory function that will return a file object.

In python 3.0 `file` is going to move from being a built-in to being implemented by multiple classes in the `io` library (somewhat similar to Java with buffered readers, etc.)

Comment: Two reasons for what?

Answer (score 19):

`file()` is a type, like an int or a list. `open()` is a function for opening files, and will return a `file` object.

This is an example of when you should use open:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f:
    process(line)
f.close()
```

This is an example of when you should use file:

```
class LoggingFile(file):
    def write(self, data):
        sys.stderr.write("Wrote %d bytes\n" % len(data))
        super(LoggingFile, self).write(data)
```

As you can see, there's a good reason for both to exist, and a clear use-case for both.

Comment: Generally, files should be opened with the `with` statement. `with open(filename, 'r') as f: \ for line in f: \ process(line)`. This avoids the explicit close. Python 2.6 and above natively support the `with` statement. In Python 2.5, you must add `from __future__ import with_statement` to the top of your code.

Comment: Didn't you just redefine the built-in name in the second example?

Comment: @planetp, the second example just inherits from the file class. I suppose it's weird that it's in lower case, but that's how it is with the basic builtin types (e.g. object, str, list, ...)

Comment: In Python 2.5, the `file` class was equipped with special methods that are automatically called whenever a file is opened via a `with` statement. These special methods ensure that the file is properly and safely opened and closed.

Answer (score 7):

Functionally, the two are the same; `open` will call `file` anyway, so currently the difference is a matter of style. The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/lib/built-in-funcs.html) recommend using `open`.

> When opening a file, it's preferable to use open() instead of invoking the file constructor directly.

The reason is that in future versions they is not guaranteed to be the same (`open` will become a factory function, which returns objects of  different types depending on the path it's opening).

Comment: open is already a factory function, so there are functional differences (eg. inheritance, isinstance() etc)

Answer (score 4):

Only ever use open() for opening files. file() is actually being removed in 3.0, and it's deprecated at the moment. They've had a sort of strange relationship, but file() is going now, so there's no need to worry anymore.

The following is from the Python 2.6 docs. [bracket stuff] added by me.

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking this [file()] constructor directly. file is more suited to type testing (for example, writing isinstance(f, file)

Answer (score 2):

According to Mr Van Rossum, although open() is currently an alias for file() you should use open() because this might change in the future.