# How to convert base64 string to image?

Tags: python, base64

I'm converting an image to **base64** string and sending it from android device to the server. Now, I need to change that string back to an image and save it in the database.

Any help?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

Try this:

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
# f gets closed when you exit the with statement
# Now save the value of filename to your database
```

Comment: @rmunn...what does 'wb' point for?!

Comment: @omarsafwany It means "w"rite and "b"inary 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665866/what-is-the-wb-mean-in-this-code-using-python

Comment: @rmunn : Thanks you so much for those lines ! I know, comments are not made to say thanks but you really save my time !

Comment: This created a broken image for me.

Comment: @JoshUsre - If you got a broken image from this sample code, it's probably because the base64 data you're decoding isn't a valid JPEG. It might be a different type of image -- a PNG or a GIF, for example -- and figuring out what kind of image you have is outside the scope of this answer. But try to create a file with the right extension for the kind of image you have, and see if that works. And if you still have trouble, ask a real question rather than dropping a one-sentence comment in a two-year-old post. A real question will get FAR more attention, and better answers.

Comment: @rmunn What if I want to display image using opencv? without saving it to any file.

Comment: @JumabekAlikhanov - You should ask a new question about that. Adding a comment to my answer only notifies one person (me), but a new question will be seen by thousands of people, who will probably know opencv much better than I do. From what I've seen of the opencv documentation, I only know how to open an image from a file, so your "without saving it to any file" will need to be answered by someone else. So ask a new question and give enough details, and hopefully someone will know how to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 31):

Convert base64_string into opencv (RGB):

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2

# Take in base64 string and return cv image
def stringToRGB(base64_string):
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string))
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    opencv_img= cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return opencv_img
```

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Link only comments are discouraged for a reason that contents might change or disappear at all. Please add your approach as an answer from the next time.

Answer (score 8):

Just use the method `.decode('base64')` and go to be happy.

You need, too, to detect the mimetype/extension of the image, as you can save it correctly, in a brief example, you can use the code below for a django view:

```
def receive_image(req):
    image_filename = req.REQUEST["image_filename"] # A field from the Android device
    image_data = req.REQUEST["image_data"].decode("base64") # The data image
    handler = open(image_filename, "wb+")
    handler.write(image_data)
    handler.close()
```

And, after this, use the file saved as you want.

Simple. Very simple. ;)

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
image = open("image.png", "wb")
image.write(base64string.decode('base64'))
image.close()
```

Comment: I used this method. I like it because it's pretty much the simplest and closest to the results I want - which is basically turning the string into an image file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using open-cv to save the file since it helps with image type conversions internally. The sample code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def save(encoded_data, filename):
    nparr = np.fromstring(encoded_data.decode('base64'), np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
    return cv2.imwrite(filename, img)
```

Then somewhere in your code you can use it like this:

```
save(base_64_string, 'testfile.png');
save(base_64_string, 'testfile.jpg');
save(base_64_string, 'testfile.bmp');
```