# How to convert a base64 byte to image in python

Tags: python, django, base64

I am facing a problem in converting base64byte to image.I tried this

```
filename="chart.png"
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
       f.write(base64.decodebytes(data))
```

where the base64byte is sored in data (like this b'iV.....'.after this i tried uploading the "filename" to my django database by doing

```
gimage.objects.create(name='Rufus5', pic1=filename)
```

.this creates an empty file chart.png in my django database.

Answer (score 1):

you can use django's default functionality

```
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile

gimage.objects.create(name='Rufus5', pic1=ImageFile(open("chart.png", "rb")))
```

Comment: this doesnt include anywhere how should i inject the base64 byte in the image

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import base64
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
filename = 'some_image.jpg'  # I assume you have a way of picking unique filenames
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
# f gets closed when you exit the with statement
# Now save the value of filename to your database
```

the anser is founded in : [How to convert base64 string to image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214190/how-to-convert-base64-string-to-image/16214280)