# Why write in binary data form in Python?

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python and I don't understand the difference between writing to a file in the normal text form and in the binary data form. From what I've been reading it has something to do with the carriage return symbols and the variance between Windows and Linux. Can somebody give me a clear explanation and example maybe? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the 'wb' mean in this code.. using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665866/what-is-the-wb-mean-in-this-code-using-python)

Comment: see http://www.fileinfo.com/help/binary_vs_text_files