# Can't Extract Image From PHP in Python

Tags: python, image, download, urllib

I'm trying to build a program in Python that will scrape a website for an image and download it, but the website returns this link:

http://www.tapmusic.net/lastfm/collage.php?user=kogam7&type=7day&size=5x5

Which doesn't have a *.jpg or *.png extension. So when I try to use the following code:

```
import urllib , urllib2, os , sys , time
img = urllib.urlopen("http://www.tapmusic.net/lastfm/collage.php?user=kogam7&amp;type=7day&amp;size=5x5").read()
hand0 = open("test.jpg" , "w")
hand0.write(img)
hand0.close()
```

It writes an image that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWCBg.jpg

Does anyone know what's going wrong?

Comment: I have just tried the script, it works fine here. (OS X)

Comment: Using Windows, sorry

Answer (score 1):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

# Use 'wb' over 'w' 
with open('image.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(urlopen('http://www.tapmusic.net/lastfm/collage.php?user=kogam7&type=7day&size=5x5').read())
```

Learn more about what 'wb' stands for and why it is required on windows.

> [What is the 'wb' mean in this code, using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665866/what-is-the-wb-mean-in-this-code-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You must open the output file in binary mode by passing `"wb"` to `open()`. This is significant if you are using Windows (which I assume you are because your code should otherwise work), i.e.

```
import urllib , urllib2, os , sys , time
img = urllib.urlopen("http://www.tapmusic.net/lastfm/collage.php?user=kogam7&amp;type=7day&amp;size=5x5").read()
hand0 = open("test.jpg" , "wb")
hand0.write(img)
hand0.close()
```