# Unzip csv file from Zip on ftp server

Tags: python-2.7, ftp, zip

I want to log into a ftp server (not a public url) and download a csv file which is located in a zip file and then save this to a particular directory:

```
#log in OK

# this is the zip file I want to download
fpath = strDate + ".zip"

#set where to save file
ExtDir = "A:\\LOCAL\\DIREC\\TORY\\"""
ExtDir = ExtDir + strdate + "\\"
ExtFile = ExtDir + "Download.zip"

#download files
#use zipfile.ZipFile as alternative method to open(ExtFile, 'w')
with zipfile.ZipFile(ExtFile,'w') as outzip:
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % fpath , outzip.write)
outzip.close
```

I get this error

> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\ftplib.py", line 419, in retrbinary callback(data)
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 2.7\lib\zipfile.py", line 1123, in write st = os.stat(filename)
>   TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Comment: Could you try with `open(ExtFile, 'wb')` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2665873

Comment: it just gives me an error 
"IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"
As this 'wb' doesn't make a file. If I use 
`open(ExtFile, 'w')` and then close it afterwards, I get a zip file created but I can't open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using:

```
ftp.retrlines('RETR %s' % fpath ,lambda s, w=outzip.write: w(s+"\n"))
```