# Issue in storing variable data using writerow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have following code writing CSV data to a file

```
with open('data-file.csv','wb') as myfile:
  wrtr = csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  data = [time.strftime('%H:%M:%S'),int(round((value2 - value) / 1, 2))]
  wrtr.writerow(data)
```

I am retrieving below error, I tried to solve it but I am unable

```
 wrtr.writerow(data)
 TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Use `w` instead of  `wb`

Comment: Can you open the file with "w" instead of "wb"? If it doesn't work, we can encode.

Comment: @HirushaFernando , for pointing out this its now working using w instead of wb

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure since I can not reproduce the code with any data example, but the problem probably lies within the open method, you chose 'wb' write binary. Therefore you need to provide binary data(not string data). I will not go into detail because this has already been done in other posts. As solution choose a different opening style like 'w' or 'w+', this different opening style they says that you can also provide text data in this case string objects.

[Link to related stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665866/what-does-wb-mean-in-this-code-using-python)

[Link to Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)