# In Python, how do I convert a .exe file to a string of 1s and 0s?

Tags: python, binary

I seem to be able to find information on how to do this in C#, but not on how to perform the same operation in Python.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This would of course apply to any kind of file, not just exe files. Or do you want to extract a specific piece of the exe file?

Answer (score 4):

```
def padded_bin(number, width=8, padchar='0'):
    return bin(number)[2:].rjust(width, padchar)

with open(r'C:\path\to\file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    as_binary = ''.join(padded_bin(ord(c)) for c in f.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join((map(''.join, itertools.product(*['01']*8))[ord(c)]
         for c in open('foo').read()))
```

Comment: I completely forgot about `bin`, and I couldn’t resist terse and unreadable.

Comment: Actually a look up table wouldn't be that bad in this case.  However it would be bad if you recalculate that table for every character in your file.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
print "".join(bin(ord(c))[2:] for c in file("a.exe", "rb").read())
```

update with padding:

```
print "".join(("00000000"+bin(ord(c))[2:])[:8] for c in file("a.exe", "rb").read())
```

Comment: why `file` instead of `open` ?

Comment: You would have to pad the binary representation to be 8 bits however.

Comment: @F.C: good question. In order to answer I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/112970/python-when-to-use-file-vs-open and learned something new :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `open` with 'rb' as flags. That would read the file in binary mode