# Why is open() preferable over file() in Python?

Tags: python, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python - When to use file vs open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112970/python-when-to-use-file-vs-open)

From the official python documentation,

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#file

> When opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking
>   this constructor directly

But it doesn't give a reason.

Comment: For starters, it is gone in Python 3. Though that's a consequence and reinforcement, not a reason.

Comment: @delnan What type does `open` return in py3 then?

Comment: I'm not positive on this, so I won't make an answer for it, but it may have to do with how Python handles the "with" keyword. I'm unsure if you can use "with" with a constructor.

Comment: @Marcin One of the types in `io`.

Comment: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/a' mode='w+' encoding='UTF-8'>

Comment: @ВидулПетров Nope, this question already presupposes `open` is preferable and asks *why*, which that question does not answer.

Comment: @StormKiernan: both `file` and `open` work with the `with`-statement. Anything that defines correct `__enter__()`, `__exit__()` methods would work.

Comment: @drjd Not always. With a `rb` "mode", I get a `BufferedReader`. Chances are there are even more variations.

Comment: @delnan thanks for that, but you can be sure, that the object has a read method if you open it in read mode and a write method if you open it in write mode

Comment: History investigation waypoint: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4dd52ba52de8/Doc/lib/libfuncs.tex

Comment: 'Fred' is Fred Drake, and the 'discussion' would almost certainly have been in email, probably on the python dev list.

Comment: and from 2.2 docs "The file() constructor is new in Python 2.2. The previous spelling, open(), is retained for compatibility, and is an alias for file().
" so I would guess just a design error in adding file()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

So either `file` or `open` should go.

```
>>> type(file)
<type 'type'>
>>> type(open)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

`open` is a function that can return anything. `file()` returns only `file` objects.

Though it seems `open` returns only `file` objects on Python 2. And before Python 2.5 `file` and `open` are the same object.

As @gnibbler suggested in the comments the original reason for the existence of `file` might be to use it as the name for base classes.

Also, `file()` in principle could return other types as for example `int()` did on earlier Python versions:

```
>>> type(int(2**64)) is long
True
>>> type(int()) is int
True
>>> int is long
False
```

This answer is very similar to [@Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112989/4279).

In addition [BDFL said](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/60890):

> "The file class is new in Python 2.2.  It represents the type (class)
>   of objects returned by the built-in open() function.  Its constructor
>   is an alias for open(), but *for future and backwards compatibility*,
>   open() remains preferred." <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Does it actually do return anything but `file` objects?

Comment: @delnan: as far as I know it returns `file` objects on Python 2. It returns objects of different types on Python 3.

Comment: Originally `file` was and alias of `open` because it seemed awkward to subclass `open`

Comment: @gnibbler: It was before Python 2.5

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Seeing as `file` is gone, this may be the reason for removal in Python 3 (though research is warranted). It's not really a reason for avoiding it in Python 2, as the docs seem to actively encourage that `isinstance(open(<anything>), file)`.

Comment: My own idiosyncratic view: `for file in files:` is so natural and Pythonic that making it clobber a builtin always seemed like a misstep.  I've been using `for file in files:` anyway, just because I like the look of it.