# Sending an image from html to python script through CGI

Tags: javascript, python, html, post, cgi

I have a file input element on my HTML page like so :

input type="file"

which receives the path to an image file chosen by the user.

I need to pass this image to a python script for the remainder of the processing. How do I go about doing this? I'm familiar with CGI and its working. I am unclear on how I would send the image per se.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload a File with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166158/upload-a-file-with-python)

Comment: Please add the relevant code that you have now including the whole HTML form

Comment: @twil, this was not EXACTLY my problem, but the solution was along the lines of what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the "enctype" field:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_file.py" method="post">
```

in your HTML form. it is unclear whether you did or not, since you only provided partial information. Please have a look at http://webpython.codepoint.net/cgi_file_upload for a detailed explanation on how to proceed.