# File reading with Python

Tags: python, html

I have a system to *load image files* from html but once I select my file and load it from the front end I need a python api to read that image file I select. **How can I connect python to my html?**
So, to be specific it would be to load an image file with html and have my python api (I use flask) download it and read it to extract data.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbyq0.png)

The html to load the file would be:

```html
 <form action="" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="file" name="file">
                        <input class="button button-block button-primary" type="submit" value="Upload">
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The python API to download and read the file would be:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from PIL import Image

# instance of the Flask object
app = Flask(__name__)
# Carpeta de subida
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Archivos GTiff'


@app.route("/")
@app.route("imgeo/upload-img.html")
def upload_file():
    # render the template "upload-img.html"
    return render_template('upload-img.html')


@app.route('imgeo/upload-img.html')
def viewer():
    """Show a map to view the GeoJSON returned from a ImGeo endpoint"""
    return render_template('imgeo/upload-img.html')


@app.route("imgeo/upload-img.html", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # we get the file from the "file" input
        f = request.files['archivo']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        # Save the file in the directory "tiff files".
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # We return a satisfactory answer
        return "<h1>File uploaded successfully</h1>"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the application
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to encode your image in base64 with JavaScript, send the result with a POST request, and then (in Python) decode it. Check out these two threads:

[How can I convert an image into Base64 string using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript) (JavaScript)

[Convert string in base64 to image and save on filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323128/convert-string-in-base64-to-image-and-save-on-filesystem) (Python)

Here is a similar question too:

[Sending an image from html to python script through CGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579156/sending-an-image-from-html-to-python-script-through-cgi)