When (and why) did Python2's built-in `file()` get deprecated?
I recently had to port some ancient Python2 code to Python3 and bumped into the use of the file built-in function instead of open I've been used to.
Interestingly there was no reference to file being deprecated and also the 2to3 tool did not report that this has or should be changed.
Could anyone point me to a document explaining what happened?

What makes you think file  got deprecated? Python 2.7 and Python 3.0 was a breaking change for a myriad of reasons, it was removed then, what would be the point of a deprecation period?

I believe the link to the version update that removed it can be found in the top answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112970/python-when-to-use-file-vs-open

@wim OK, I used "deprecated" when I should've really used "removed".  But the fact that not even the 2to3 tool convert file to open baffles me, when all there is in terms of documentation is a short line in the 3.0 What's New page as found with the suggested duplicate.  Should I edit the question to change to "removed"?

Looks like it was removed in this commit. No commentary is provided, but it looks like it was already aliased to open(), so they were probably just tidying up the builtins namespace.
